# PDFBox not working when try getSignatureDictionaries

Tags: java, pdfbox, signature

I am using PDFBox to extract my PDFs signatures. In the version 2.0.24 the simple `PDDocument.load(File file)` got an unusual time. I upgraded to 3.0.0.-alpha, the `Loader.loadPDF(File file)` had a good time, but in the next step, when I try to extract the signatures I got terribly slow and it never ends.

```
for (PDSignature sig : document.getSignatureDictionaries()) {
    COSDictionary sigDictionary = sig.getCOSObject();
    COSString contents = (COSString) sigDictionary.getDictionaryObject(COSName.CONTENTS);

    String subFilter = sig.getSubFilter();
    if (subFilter != null) {
        PDFResult pdfResult = new PDFResult();
        pdfResult.setName(sig.getName());
        pdfResult.setContactInfo(sig.getContactInfo());
        pdfResult.setLocation(sig.getLocation());
        pdfResult.setReason(sig.getReason());
        pdfResult.setFilter(sig.getFilter());
        pdfResult.setSignDate(sig.getSignDate().getTime());
        pdfResult.setSubFilter(subFilter);

        switch (subFilter) {
            case "adbe.pkcs7.detached":
            case "ETSI.CAdES.detached":
                verifyPKCS7(getSignedContent(sig, contents), contents, pdfResult);
                break;
            case "adbe.pkcs7.sha1": {
                byte[] hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1").digest(getSignedContent(sig, contents));
                verifyPKCS7(hash, contents, pdfResult);
                break;
            }
            case "adbe.x509.rsa_sha1":
                COSString certString = (COSString) sigDictionary.getDictionaryObject(COSName.CERT);
                if (certString == null) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("The /Cert certificate string is missing in the pdfResult dictionary");
                }
                CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                ByteArrayInputStream certStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(certString.getBytes());
                Collection<? extends Certificate> certs = factory.generateCertificates(certStream);

                X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certs.iterator().next();

                pdfResult.setCertificate(new br.com.fiorilli.signature.utils.model.Certificate(cert));
                pdfResult.setCertificateEncoded(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cert.getEncoded()));
                break;
            case "ETSI.RFC3161":
                verifyETSIdotRFC3161(contents, pdfResult);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IOException("Unknown certificate type: " + subFilter);
        }
        signatures.add(pdfResult);
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Missing subfilter for cert dictionary");
    }
}
```

This happens only with specific PDFs, like this. Java starts to use high cpu and the process never ends.

Comment: Please share the PDF. I wonder if there is a loop in the field tree.

Comment: I tried the ShowSignature example and it works fine. Make sure your classpath is clean, i.e. only one version.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look.

Comment: How much memory does the code test have assigned? And which JRE version are you using?

Comment: Also please clarify what you mean by "terribly slow". Seconds? Minutes? Hours?

Comment: The code in the question looks a lot like ShowSignature example. When I ran it, it took some time to load and verify all the certificates. It might take even more time if your system isn't connected to the internet or needs a proxy.

Comment: I am using jre 11 and it cost servers cpu, not memory. The server cpu got 100%.

Comment: In this case, the "terribly slow" means that the process doesn't ends. I am taking a look at ShowSignature samples. At first, the main diferrence it's how the lib open the pdf. I am using the Loader, in the sample not.

Comment: PDF link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b2WPjzpu9U4NDe-xcXxSD1u4AqZ51C-r/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Testing with ShowSignature sample the code line `for (PDSignature sig : document.getSignatureDictionaries())` take 30 seconds.

Comment: This PDF has 2 pages with 3 signatures. But one had a big byte code.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was follow all the implementation on ShowSignature sample. My verifyPKCS7 method was little bit different. For similar problems, follow the ShowSignature sample in  github:

https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/ShowSignature.java